# System configuration program with changeable frames

Tags: python, function, tkinter, get, haskell-src-exts

I am new Python, and I am trying to create a system configuration window, but I have a problem with the buttons, when I press the user button the users configuration appears, I press the mouse button, the mouse configuration appears, but if I press again the users button no longer appears the user settings.
So far I have this...

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess as sh

PYTHON_VERSION = sys.version_info.major
if PYTHON_VERSION < 3:
    try:
        from Tkinter import *
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError("Se requiere el modulo tkinter")
else:
    try:
        from tkinter import *
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError("Se requiere el modulo tkinter")

class app(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('900x900')
        self.menu = Frame(self)
        self.menu.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.user = Frame(self)
        self.mouse = Frame(self)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        for i in range(3):
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        Label(self.menu, text='MENÚ').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        Label(self.mouse,text='MOUSE').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.i = "img/usuarios.png"
        self.i = PhotoImage(file=self.i)
        self.i = self.i.zoom(3)
        self.i = self.i.subsample(25)
        Label(self.user, image=self.i).grid(row=2, column=1)
        Label(self.user, text="Cuentas de Usuarios", fg="red", font=("slender", 20)).grid(row=2, column=2)

        # Agregar Usuario
        self.im = "img/añadir.png"
        self.im = PhotoImage(file=self.im)
        self.im = self.im.zoom(2)
        self.im = self.im.subsample(24)
        Label(self.user, image=self.im).grid(row=5, column=0)
        Label(self.user, text="Agregar Usuario", fg="red", font=("ComicRelief", 12)).grid(row=5, column=1)

        # Nombre de Usuario
        Label(self.user, text="Usuario:", font=("ComicRelief",10, "bold")).grid(row=7, column=1)
        self.users = Entry(self.user)
        self.users.grid(row=7, column=2)

        # Password
        Label(self.user, text="Password:", font=("ComicRelief",10, "bold")).grid(row=9, column=1)
        self.passwd = Entry(self.user, show="*")
        self.passwd.grid(row=9, column=2)

        # Grupos
        Label(self.user, text="Grupos Alternos:", font=("ComicRelief",10, "bold")).grid(row=11, column=1)
        self.grupo = Entry(self.user)
        self.grupo.grid(row=11, column=2)

        def new():
            self.file = open("/home/lcp/.sistema/programas/configuracion/doc/nuevo_usuario.lcp", "w")
            self.file.write("#!/bin/sh" + os.linesep)
            self.file.write("doas adduser -n " + str( self.users.get()))
            self.file.close()
            sh.run(["chmod", "+x", "/home/lcp/.sistema/programas/configuracion/doc/nuevo_usuario.lcp"])
            #self.users.sh.run(["/home/lcp/.sistema/programas/configuracion/doc/nuevo_usuario.ilcp"])

        self.crear = Button(self.user, text="Crear Usuario", command=new)
        self.crear.grid(row=15, column=2)

        self.scl = Scale(self.mouse, from_=1, to=20, tickinterval=2, length=400, resolution=1, showvalue=NO, orient='horizontal', label="Pointer Speed")
        self.scl.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='nse')

        def velocity():
            self.file = open("/home/lcp/.sistem/widgets/configuration/doc/mouse.lcp", "w")
            self.file.write("#!/bin/sh" + os.linesep)
            self.file.write("xset m " + str( self.scl.get())+ " 1")
            self.file.close()
            sh.run(["chmod", "+x", "/home/lcp/.sistem/widgets/configuration/doc/mouse.lcp"])
            sh.run(["/home/lcp/.sistem/widgets/configuration/doc/mouse.lcp"])

        self.apply = Button(self.mouse, text="Apply", command=velocity)
        self.apply.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky='nse')

        # Button User Account
        self.usr = Button(self.menu,text="User Account",width=20,command=self.users)
        self.usr.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nse')

        # Button Mouse
        self.raton = Button(self.menu, text="Mouse",width=20,command=self.moused)
        self.raton.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nse')
        #self.status = False  
    # 
    def users(self):
        #if self.status:
        #    self.user.grid_forget()
        #    self.user.status = False

        #else:
        #    self.status = True
            self.user.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky='nsew')

    # Mouse Action    
    def moused(self):
        #if self.status:
        #    self.mouse.grid_forget()
        #    self.status = False

        #else:
        #    self.status = True
            self.mouse.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky='nsew')

app().mainloop()
```

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see if you get error message ?

Comment: user setting are behind mouse settings. You have to hide mouse settings using `grid_forget()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems

1) you use name `self.users` for `Entry()` and for `def users(self)` so when you click button then it doesn't execute `def users(self)`. You can see it if you use `print()` in `def users(self)` - it will not print text.

2) users settings are all time behind mouse settings - you have to hide mouse settings to see users settings.

```
    # Button User Account
    self.usr = Button(self.menu,text="User Account",width=20,command=self.users_setting)
    self.usr.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nse')

    # Button Mouse
    self.raton = Button(self.menu, text="Mouse",width=20,command=self.mouse_settings)
    self.raton.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nse')

def users_setting(self):
    print('show user settings')
    self.user.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky='nsew')
    self.mouse.grid_forget()

# Mouse Action    
def mouse_settings(self):
    print('show mouse settings')
    self.mouse.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky='nsew')
    self.user.grid_forget()
```

Comment: It's perfect, Thanks